# Should I use "meet" or "know" when referring to a fictional character?

Tags: verbs

My native language is Portuguese, but I can understand a lot of English, especially when reading or listening to something. However, sometimes, I get stuck on a few things when writing.

When referring to a fictional character, should I use "meet" or "know"?

> Marcus Kane is one of the most touching characters I've ever been
> lucky enough to **meet/know** and certainly one of Ian's best works.

Thank you!

Comment: **Encounter** is more natural in this context.

Comment: I think that **meet** sounds better to me, as **know** implies an ongoing relationship. Both usages imply that you are blurring the distinction between reality and fiction (which may be OK in your setting). More formally, I'd write *Marcus is one of the most touching characters in Ian's works*